# Special join of two tables using date range

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have two tables in the MariaDB database used for my thesis, one with financial company years and one with patent data. The patent data table (Table A) looks like

```
    Company | Publication_number | Application_Date | Document_Type | Country_Code | ...
    A       | US2019xxxx         | 2018-12-01       | application   | US           | ...
    A       | WO2018xxxx         | 2018-12-01       | application   | WO           | ...
    A       | US2018xxxx         | 2017-09-23       | application   | WO           | ...
    B       | EP3285xxxx         | 2018-09-23       | patent        | EP           | ...
    B       | US2019xxxx         | 2019-01-27       | patent        | EP           | ...
    ...
```

The table with financial years (Table B) looks like:

```
    Company | Financial_Year | Financial_Year_Start | Financial_Year_End
    A       | 2018           | 2018-01-01           | 2018-12-31
    A       | 2017           | 2017-01-01           | 2017-12-31
    B       | 2018           | 2018-04-01           | 2019-03-31
    ...
```

What I would like to have is a table (Table C) like:

```
    Company | Publication number | Application Date | Financial Year | Document Type | Country Code | ...
    A       | US2019xxxx         | 2018-12-01       | 2018           | application   | US           | ...
    A       | WO2018xxxx         | 2018-12-01       | 2018           | application   | WO           | ...
    A       | US2016xxxx         | 2017-09-23       | 2017           | application   | WO           | ...
    B       | EP3285xxxx         | 2018-09-23       | 2018           | patent        | EP           | ...
    B       | US2019xxxx         | 2019-01-27       | 2018           | patent        | EP           | ...
    ...
```

Seems easy enough, but I haven't found a way to assign the financial year properly using the start and end dates. Unfortunately financial years do not always coincide with calender years. Can anyone tell me how to approach this problem? I have hundrets of thousands of patent documents in my table, so manually assigning financial years is not an option.

The final target is to have a derived basic statistic table looking this (Table D):

```
    Company | Financial Year | Count US Applications | Count US patents | Count EP Applications | ...
    A       | 2018           | 89                    | 12               | 56                    | ...
    A       | 2017           | 93                    | 26               | 64                    | ...
    B       | 2018           | 53                    | 5                | 49                    | ...
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine what exactly was your problem when joining the two tables. Maybe you should have shown some queries you tried, so we could have told you what you got wrong. Anyway, I have posted an answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aSYx45FKaWnpKoKFxCTGzB/1) (in PostgreSQL) but you can apply same thing in MariaDB.

```
select
    p.Company,
    Publication_number,
    Application_Date,
    Financial_Year,
    Document_Type,
    Country_Code
from patent p
join financial_years fy
on p.Company = fy.Company
and Application_Date between
    Financial_Year_Start and Financial_Year_End
```

and for your final result you can do something like this with `case` statement

```
select
    Company,
    Financial_Year,
    sum(case when Country_Code = 'US' and Document_Type = 'patent' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Count US patents',
    sum(case when Country_Code = 'US' and Document_Type = 'application' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Count US applications',
    sum(case when Country_Code = 'EP' and Document_Type = 'patent' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Count EP patents',
    sum(case when Country_Code = 'EP' and Document_Type = 'application' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Count RP applications'
from yourTable
group by
    Company,
    Financial_Year
order by
    Financial_Year
```

Comment: Why do you put one of the two join criteria in the `WHERE` clause instead of the `ON` clause? And what made you decide which of the two to have in `ON` and which in `WHERE`? I don't understand your rationale behind this. Apart from your placing the criteria, this is the same join as in my answer. (It is not considered good style by the way to leave columns unqualified when dealing with multiple tables.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for the feedback. I think putting `WHERE` condition is more easy to read when you are doing a inner join. but I will do in your style when I use `left join` as I have experienced that when I use `WHERE`  in `left join` then it convert it into `inner join`. I may be wrong but open to accept any suggestions.

Comment: You are supposed to put all join criteria in the `ON` clauses. The tables are related by company and dates, so both criteria belong there. If we had *additional* criteria, say `financial_year in (2018, 2019)` we'd be free to put it in `where` or `on`. The idea with placing it in `where` is that the desired years is no criterion that actually links the tables. The idea with `on` is that you join the fiscal years on matching company, range and desired years. Both argumentations are fine, and we decide based on readability and usability, just as you describe...

Comment: If we placed `financial_year in (2018, 2019)` in `where` it would be obvious on first glance that this query is about these two fiscal years. If we placed it in `on` we could easily switch from inner to outer join. Exactly as you said. Anyway, with such criteria, we might swap the join completely anyway. I.e. a query on the years 2018 and 2019 would probably written as `from financial_years fy [left] join patent p on ... where financial_year in (2018, 2019)` from the start and the typical outer join (selecting years even when they have no patents) would be covered.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you! :) , I have updated my demo link and answer both.

Comment: You are welcome. And your answer is good. (While it might have been good practice for OP to try the aggregation step by step themselves for the learning purpose :-) In MariaDB (like in MySQL) there is `true = 1` and `false = 0`, so you could shorten the conditional aggregation expressions to `sum(Country_Code = 'US' and Document_Type = 'patent')` etc.

Comment: It worked like a charm including counting the document type by years, many thanks again.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . Not only does the answer miss the simpler syntax, but it also doesn't qualify the column names.  It works, but I would hesitate to call the code "good".

Answer (score 1):

The tables are related by company and date range, so join on these. This should simply be:

```
select *
from a
join b on a.company = b.company
      and a.application_date between b.financial_year_start and b.financial_year_end;
```